# Excel - How to enter an array based on cell keyword

Tags: excel

What I'm trying to accomplish is to use validate to add an array drop down list in a cell. The trick is I need to provide different arrays based on a keyword from another cell.

For example. If I have cell named "Campaign Name" and in that cell, if it doesn't contain the keyword cross-network, then I need to display a digital sources array in a different cell. If the keyword cross-network does appear, then I need I need to display a print sources array.

See this diagram.

[image: Sample Excel layout]

I've tried several formulas and `ChatGPT`, but they all want to look for a keyword in a list and filter or create a row / column with the filtered results.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out, it was much simpler than I was making it.

I just needed a simple if statement in the validation key.

=if('Campaign Names'!H5<>"cross-network", 'Table Arrays'!$B$4:$B$824, 'Table Arrays'!$C$4:$C$23)

I was trying to make this work with array names and not the cell range, which was throwing me off.